# ¿Cómo trabajar con rutas con espacios en Linux desde Python 2.7?

Tags: python, linux

Tengo un script en Python que procesa archivos en una carpeta en Linux Mint. Parte del código se ve como esto:

```
path_to_dir = "/home/user/Im a folder with libs to install/"

if os.path.isdir(path_to_dir):
    print "Puede localizar el directorio"
    os.chdir(path_to_dir) # todo bien aquí :D
    subprocess.call(['./configure'], shell = True)
    subprocess.call(['make'], shell = True)
    subprocess.call(['make install'], shell = True) # el problema ocurre aquí
```

Cuando ejecuto `subprocess.call(['make install'], shell = True)` arroja el siguiente error:

```
/bin/bash: /home/user/Im: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 127
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

¿cómo puedo trabajar con rutas con espacios cuando ejecuto `subprocess.call(['make install'], shell = True)`? (Estoy usando Python 2.7)

Comment: diría que el problema está en el script del make. Si olvidamos por un momento Python, y ejecutas ese código "a mano" desde la consola, ubicado en dicha carpeta, ¿logras hacer el make install correctamente?

Comment: He ejecutado las sentencias desde la terminal y sucede lo mismo: "./configure" y "make" ejecutan bien, pero al hacer "make install" me arroja exactamente el error mostrado. El problema no es Python, parece que el make de esta librería no soporta espacios en la ruta en la que está. Quisiera saber si existe un "workaround" para este problema antes de arrojarle al usuario el mensaje "Póngame estas librerías en una ruta sin espacios"

Comment: Tendríamos que saber cómo es el makefile, uno que tenga el mínimo tamaño posible que reproduce el error, y qué versión de make utilizas.

Comment: Has intentado usando `path_to_dir = r"/home/user/Im a folder with libs to install/"` (nota la `r` antes de la ruta)
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema no está en python.

Utilizando el siguiente makefile el programa de la pregunta funciona bien.

```
#Makefile

all : 
    touch "/tmp/a.obj"

install :
    touch "/home/user/Im a folder with libs to install/a.bin"
```

- `subprocess.call(['make'], shell = True)` crea el fichero a.obj en /temp.
- `subprocess.call(['make install'], shell = True)` crea el fichero a.bin en la carpeta con espacios.

Comment: Es cierto, el problema no es Python! el archivo Makefile de las librerías le pasa al bash de linux la ruta sin caracteres de escape de modo que no acepta los espacios. Voy a tener que avisar a los usuarios.